# C++ how to pass variable into function?

Tags: c++

```
void webparser()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "lynx -dump 'http://somesite.com/q?s=" << currency << "=X' > file.txt";
    system(ss.str().c_str());
}
```

How do i pass e.g "GBPUSD" into webparser if i want use GBPUSD as a char chArray[];
and then assign the passed value as variable currency in my case

Thanks, no return is require.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, that's a very basic part of functions: parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
void webparser(const std::string& currency) {
  stringstream ss;
  ss << "lynx -dump 'http://somesite.com/q?s=" << currency << "=X' > file.txt";
  system(ss.str().c_str());
}
```

Call the function:

```
webparser("Hello, World!");
```